# Enabling SQL statements for SQLAlchemy / Pyramid from the command line

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I am using Pyramid with SQLAlchemy, and I have the following section in my `development.ini`:

```
[logger_sqlalchemy]
# level = INFO
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine
```

Whenever I want to enable SQL statement / echo, I edit that file and change the comment so it becomes `level = INFO`.

My question is how can I do this from the command line, without editing the file in a text editor.

Other web frameworks have built-in support for this, but I couldn't find a solution for Pyramid / SQLAlchemy.

I'd like to support `pserve`, `pshell`, and `alembic`.

Comment: This does not solve for your problem, but to address issues like this I built a layered INI configuration files for Websauna, see example https://github.com/websauna/myapp/blob/master/conf/development.ini, docs  https://websauna.org/reference/config.html - One could simply create `development-sqlalchemy-logging.ini` which extends `development.ini`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [pyramid_sqlalchemy](http://pyramid-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), there's an option `--sql-echo` that you can use when [running tests](http://pyramid-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tests.html).

Otherwise, you will have parse the arguments yourself and set the logging level:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel('INFO')
```

For `pserve` and `pshell`, you would probably have to read the command line arguments somewhere in your app initalisation code.

For `alembic`, you would need to modify your `env.py`.